# Javascript use return value in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, return-value, deferred

What I want to achive is using the return value of the **"previewfile"** function as an execution indicator for the **"readfiles"** function. But this needs to be after the **"image.onload"** part has been executed, since there I need returnThis to be set to true.
I've researched several things on Google and Stackoverflow concerning this problem and callbacks / deferred objects in general, but I cannot wrap my head around how to applicate that in this situation.

I have the following constellation in my Image uploading section:

```
function previewfile(file, tests, acceptedTypes, holder) {
    var returnThis = false;                                                                               
    if (tests.filereader === true && acceptedTypes[file.type] === true) {                                                                
        var reader = new FileReader();                                                                                                   
        reader.onload = function (event) {                                                                                               
            var image = new Image();                                                                                
            image.onload = function() {                                                                                                  
                var testimage = new Image();                                                                                             
                testimage.src = $(this).attr('src');                                                                                     
                var widthOfImage = testimage.width;                                                                                      
                var heightOfImage = testimage.height;                                                                                    
                if (!checkImageDimensions(widthOfImage, heightOfImage)) {
                    // do stuff                                                  
                } else {
                    returnThis = true;                                                                                           
                }                                                                                                                        
            };                                                                                                                           
            image.src = event.target.result;                                                                                             
            holder.appendChild(image);                                                                                                   
        };                                                                                                                               
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);                                                                                                      
    }  else {                                                                                                                            
        // do other stuff                                                                                                              
    }                                                                                                                                    
    return returnThis;                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                        
function readfiles(files, tests, acceptedTypes, holder, progress) {                                                                      
    var uploadNow = previewfile(files[0], tests, acceptedTypes, holder);                                                                   
    if (uploadNow === true) {                                                                                                               
        // do stuff                                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                                
    } else {                                                                                                                             
        // do other stuff                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                    
}
```

Comment: What about simple callback?

Comment: @dfsq as I stated, I do not know how to use callback in this nested functions situation.

Comment: There is nothing special about this situation. Make `previewfile` accept a function and call it when the image is available.

Comment: @FelixKling Could you elaborate a little more, please? I've tried kallehj's answer, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: You have to call the callback from inside the `onload` handler and inside the `else` statement.

Comment: @FelixKling And if I do so, the rest of the function(s) (like reader.onload) are still executed?

Comment: You put `callback(returnThis);` at the end of the `image.onload` function. At that moment the `reader.onload` function already executed.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah I did that already, but because of another error (that I just found) it didn't work. You made me look closer again, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of FelixKling and kallehj, this is the working solution (with callback):

```
// important
function previewfile(file, tests, acceptedTypes, holder, callback) {
    var returnThis = false;                                                                               
    if (tests.filereader === true && acceptedTypes[file.type] === true) {                                                                
        var reader = new FileReader();                                                                                                   
        reader.onload = function (event) {                                                                                               
            var image = new Image();                                                                                
            image.onload = function() {                                                                                                  
                var testimage = new Image();                                                                                             
                testimage.src = $(this).attr('src');                                                                                     
                var widthOfImage = testimage.width;                                                                                      
                var heightOfImage = testimage.height;                                                                                    
                if (!checkImageDimensions(widthOfImage, heightOfImage)) {
                    // do stuff                                                  
                } else {
                    returnThis = true;                                                                                           
                }
                callback(returnThis);             // important                                                                                                           
            };                                                                                                                           
            image.src = event.target.result;                                                                                             
            holder.appendChild(image);                                                                                                   
        };                                                                                                                               
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);                                                                                                      
    }  else {                                                                                                                            
        callback(returnThis);                    // important                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                        
function readfiles(files, tests, acceptedTypes, holder, progress) {
    // important                                                                      
    previewfile(files[0], tests, acceptedTypes, holder, function (uploadNow) {
        if (uploadNow === true) {                                                                                                               
            // do stuff                                                                                                          
            }                                                                                                                                
        } else {                                                                                                                             
            // do other stuff                                                                                                    
        }                                                                                                                                    
    }        
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with something like this

```
function readfiles(files, tests, acceptedTypes, holder, progress) {                                                                      
    previewfile(files[0], tests, acceptedTypes, holder, function(value){
        if (uploadNow === true){                                                                                                               
             // do stuff                                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                                
        else {                                                                                                                             
            // do other stuff                                                                                                    
        } 
    });                                                                   

}

function previewfile(file, tests, acceptedTypes, holder, callback) {
    ...
    callback(returnValue); //instead of return
}
```

Comment: Though this answer was helpful, it is not completely correct. I'd accept it, but my edit to correct it (so that it is actually working) was refused. So I cannot mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As `previewfile()` relies on asynchronous activity, it is itself effectively asynchronous. As such, it can't reliably return a value, but it can return a promise.

As others have pointed out, `previewfile()` can be written to accept a callback, which would avoid the need for a promise. However, if you want a promise solution, here is one (certainly not the only one).

```
function previewfile(file, tests, acceptedTypes, holder) {
    if(tests.filereader === true && acceptedTypes[file.type] === true) {
        var reader = new FileReader(),
            image;
        var promise_a = $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            reader.onload = function(event) {
                image.attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(holder);
                dfrd.resolve();
            };
            reader.onerror = function() {
                dfrd.reject('fileReader error');
            };
        }).promise();
        var promise_b = $.Deferred(function(dfrd) {
            image = $("<img/>").on('load', function() {
                var widthOfImage = image.width;
                var heightOfImage = image.height;
                if (checkImageDimensions(widthOfImage, heightOfImage)) {
                    dfrd.resolve();
                } else {
                    //do stuff
                    dfrd.reject('image loaded but dimensions did not check out');
                }
            }).error(function() {
                dfrd.reject('image did not load');
            });
        }).promise();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return $.when(promise_a, promise_b);
    } else {
        // do other stuff
        // Also return a promise here, even if no async is involved.
    }
}
```

`readfiles()` can now be written as follows :

```
function readfiles(files, tests, acceptedTypes, holder, progress) {
    return previewfile(files[0], tests, acceptedTypes, holder).then(function() {
        // do stuff
    }).then(null, function(reason) {
        console.log(reason);// or display to the user in the DOM.
        // do other stuff
    });
}
```

The benefit of a promise-based solution is maybe not so much in handling success as managing errors. Note how a single handler reports several different types of error.